# EEVEE in viewport clipping issue

Tags: materials, uv, eevee-render-engine, normals, clipping

[image: Weird EEVEE]

I seem to be getting a kind of radial clipping of the materials in material preview mode.... as I rotate its kind of sweeping across the model, but not on all textures... Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: make sure to add a sample file to get the idea of this problem.  I think it is because of wrong settings of materials.